# Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Region.GetHrgn(Graphics g)

Tags: c#

```
Parameter is not valid.   at System.Drawing.Region.GetHrgn(Graphics g)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetHRgn(Region region)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I am getting this error when i minimize it to system tray icon.
Actually i am using list-view control Which is user-control (I extended it for my own purpose) right progress bar and link button is added in my Extended List view.
not sure why it is showing this error?.
please help me if any body know this type of error.